# window.location.href doesn't redirect unless document.write

Tags: javascript

I just started JavaScript, and tried to make a site, that redirects me, when I enter the correct password. I tried to program it to redirect even when I press enter.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>P</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function v() {
                const pw = document.getElementById('pwf').value;
                //document.write("something");
                if (pw=="Password") window.location.href = "http://google.com";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
    <form name="P" action="">
         <input type="text" id="pwf" name="pwf" onkeydown = "if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('enter').click();"><br>
         <input type="button" id="enter" value="ENTER" onclick="v(this);">
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It doesn't work unless I uncomment the document.write("something"); line, and I don't understand why.

Google Chrome

Comment: It's most likely because `if (pw=="Password")` is not `true`

Comment: I printed out pw=="Password" and it said it was true, and that doesn't explain why does it work, when I uncomment the document.write

Comment: Maybe try removing the `if`, and keep `window.location.href = "http://google.com";`, I'm sure it will redirect, `document.write` only writes your webpage with whatever content you provide to it, it doesn't redirect, there is no way that it does not redirect to google.com when `if (pw=="Password")` is `true`. Even typing `window.location.href = 'http://google.com'` in your Chrome Devtools redirects to google, let alone running the code in Javascript

Comment: Does it behave differently if you click the button or press the Enter key on the keyboard?

Comment: @Lennholm The button works always

Comment: @TrashCan If I add a line if (pw=="Password") document.write("true"); BELOW the redirect line it prints out true

Comment: Your issue is that pressing enter also submits the form. Since the form's `action` is an empty string, this reloads the page, which cancels the redirect. However, when the `document.write()` runs, this instead cancels the form submit, so now that doesn't block the redirect from happening.

Comment: document.write is 99% of the time the wrong thing to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the working tested code.

Why your redirect is not working. Form tag by defaults submits (redirects), when you keyin enter, via action attribute. So the page is reloaded in your case, where the document.location.href is not called.

The onsubmit is  returned false, is the code to implement.

Your document.write has nothing to do here on the redirect.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>P</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function v() {
                const pw = document.getElementById('pwf').value;
                // document.write("something");
                if (pw=="Password") window.location.href = "http://google.com";
            }

            function onKeydown(event){
                if (event.keyCode == 13) 
                document.getElementById('enter').click();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
    <form name="P" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
         <input type="text" id="pwf" name="pwf" onkeydown = "onKeydown(event)"><br>
         <input type="button" id="enter" value="ENTER" onclick="v(this);">
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note: the `document.write()` does prevent the form from being submitted, because it overwrites the entire document and removes the form altogether, which is why the redirect is allowed to happen when that line is uncommented.

Comment: I too thought the same. But in this case, it did not happen, because before document.write he is storing the value in pw variable

Comment: No, what I wrote is the reason for the behavior. The fact that he stored the value in a variable has nothing to do with it.